# Array of vectors to arrays of arrays in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I am struggling to cast `Array(Vector)`to `Array(Array[Double])`. I thought that I could apply `.toArray` method in `foreach` like this:

```
val cents = centers.foreach(toArray)
```

Where `centers` is an array of vectors. What is the correct way to do it?

The vectors are `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`s.

Comment: `map` instead of `foreach`. If you take a look to the [**documention**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html) of both methods, you will see that `foreach` is intended to apply a side effect to all elements of the collection _(like printing)_ and returns nothing _(the `Unit`)_. Whereas `map` takes a transformation function, and returns a new collection with the changes applied. - PS: Any reason for using **Arrays**? Those are not common in Scala, expected when performance matters.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the hint! This is an exercise where I should complete a function and the output is expected to be Array[(Double, Double)]

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've tried `map( x => x.toArray)`, it reurns something strange like [D@2eb6d34a, [D@2d73e8c4

Comment: that is the String representation of an **Array**. It means it is an array of doubles, and the hash after the `@` is the hash of the hexadecimal value of the memory address of the beginning of the array. In other words is a useless representation, but that is what we have, because arrays are not created in **Scala** but in **Java**. And that is one of _(and possibly the least important)_ reasons to prefer other collection types, like **List**, instead of **Array**.